# Drawing dots and boxes using for loop and matrix

Tags: java

I am developing a simple AI game in Java: Dots and Boxes. For now, it will be 2*2. A state is represented by two matrices: a horizontal matrix and a vertical matrix. For example: the state

```
  --   --
|    |    |
  --  
|    |    |
  --   --
```

is represented by a horizontal matrix:

```
int[][] horz = new int[][] {{1,1}, {1,0}, {1,1} };
```

and a vertical matrix:

```
int[][] ver = new int[][] { {1,1,1}, {1,1,1} };
```

Currently, I am not planning to use a GUI. I have these two matrices. So, giving them as input, what I want to do is simply display a state-like diagram (like above) in the terminal using the below code, but I am not getting the correct result.

```
for(int horz_row=0; horz_row<horz.length; horz_row++) //print horz matrix row 
{ 
    //after one row break, print the first row of vertical column 
    System.out.print(horz[horz_row][horz_col]); 
    for(int ver_row=0;ver_row<ver.length; ver_row++) //print vertical matrix, row 
    {
        System.out.print(ver[horz_row][horz_col]); 
    } 
    System.out.print("  "); 
}
```

Comment: No need for "many times". Only *2* for loops will suffice ;-)

Comment: @theHacker pretty sure he meant he tried many different ways, but none worked.

Comment: Yeah.........I meant I used many attempts......;)

Comment: Show your attempts, detail what failed, specify expected and actual output. It's unclear what you're asking or looking for here.

Comment: Unless you can share your code we really can't help you.

Comment: I'm working on it right now.

Comment: for(int horz_row=0; horz_row<horz.length; horz_row++) //print horz matrix row
{
 //after one row break, print the first row of vertical column
   
   System.out.print(horz[horz_row][horz_col]);
for(int ver_row=0;ver_row<ver.length; ver_row++) //print vertical matrix, row
{
     System.out.print(ver[horz_row][horz_col]);
}
    
       System.out.print(" ");
    
  }

Comment: @user3742245 That code would be far more useful if you could edit it into the question, rather than having it as a comment.

Comment: @user3742245 Again, you still need to explain *how* it failed and explain expected and actual output. Additionally, please edit the code into your original post and format it so it's actually readable. What you posted is extremely difficult to read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

Try it here: http://ideone.com/iv082V

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int[][] horz = new int[][] {{1,1}, {1,0}, {1,1} };
    int[][] ver  = new int[][] { {1,1,1}, {1,1,1} };

    createMatrices(horz, ver);
}

public static void createMatrices(int[][] horz, int[][] ver) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < horz.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < horz[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(horz[i][j]==1?"  -- ":"     ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int k = 0; k < ver[i].length; k++) {
            System.out.print(ver[i][k]==1?"|    ":"     ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    // print last row of hyphens
    int i = horz.length - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < horz[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(horz[i][j]==1?"  -- ":"     ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: The other answer is probably faster for large matrices (he uses StringBuilder), but since it's only 2*2, I don't know which is faster. Do some testing, (and let me know).

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] hor = new int[][] {{1,1}, {1,0}, {1,1} };
int[][] ver = new int[][] { {1,1,1}, {1,1,1} };

String[] vstr = { " ", "|" };
String[] hstr = { "  ", "--" };
for( int iRow = 0; iRow < ver.length + 1; ++iRow ){
    StringBuilder sbh = new StringBuilder( " " );
    String delh = "";
    for( int iCol = 0; iCol < hor[iRow].length; ++iCol ){
        sbh.append(delh).append( hstr[hor[iRow][iCol]] );
        delh = " ";
    }
    System.out.println(sbh.toString());
    if( iRow < ver.length ){
        StringBuilder sbv = new StringBuilder();
        String delv = "";
        for( int iCol = 0; iCol < ver[iRow].length; ++iCol ){
            sbv.append(delv).append( vstr[ver[iRow][iCol]] );
            delv = "  ";
        }
        System.out.println(sbv.toString());
    }
}
```